# Superspace as the Hilbert Space for Quantum Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, research-level, quantum-gravity

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the Ashtekar connection. Since $^{(3)}g_{AB}=i\frac{\delta}{\delta\mathcal{A}^{AB}}$ (see R. Penrose, 2004: Road to Reality. Vintage Books, 1136 pp.), the Ashtekar connection, in a way, represents the graviton. Let $\mathcal{Riem}$ denote the configuration space of GR.

If one managed to quantize the metric to yield the graviton, it would make sense to say that the $\mathcal{Riem}$ is also quantized, i.e., Wheeler's superspace becomes a Hilbert space with elements as gravitons. There is an complex inner product defined between the ``de-projections'' (the inverse projection mapping) of gravitons $\mathcal{A,A}_1$, defined as $\langle\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{A}_1\rangle$. An algebra of self-adjoint unbounded operators (of which the Hamiltonian is an element) on this quantum superspace corresponds to a set of all observables. The set of all possible states corresponds to the projective superspace.

Thus, is it possible to interpret the superspace as a Hilbert space (as mentioned above)and provide a rigorous mathematical formulation of quantum gravity?

Comment: Wheeler superspace is the configuration space of "the cosmos" for a given cosmological model. The Hilbert space of states is instead formed by wave functions on that superspace. Gravitons are hard to see in this perspective, which is non-perturbative if done right (which is a big "if").

Comment: The configuration space of a mechanical system forms the cotangent bundle of the configuration space. Thus, since Wheeler's superspace is the configuration space of "the cosmos", it should be possible to construct a Hilbert space after quantizing the superspace.

Comment: Sorry - it should instead be a projective Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes, you can imagine building a Hilbert space of wavefunctions on Wheeler superspace. But it is not possible to "interpret superspace as a Hilbert space" (it's not even a vector space, to begin with), which is what you were asking.

Comment: In Quantum Gravity, Claus Kiefer, Kiefer says that $\mathcal{Riem}\Sigma$ is a cone in the vector space $V$ of all symmetric second-rank tensor fields. I.e., $\mathcal{Riem}\Sigma=(V \times I)/(V \times \{0\})$. Thus, shouldn't $\mathcal{Riem}$ be a vector space too? Since superspace is a $\mathcal{Riem}/\mathcal{Diff}$, one is just removing diffeomorphism invariance from $\mathcal{Riem}$, but this still preserves the topology of $\mathcal{Riem}$ - i.e., superspace is a vector space. Of course, I may be wrong in assuming that a cone of a vector space is another vector space.

Comment: Take that as an exercise, to see that metrics don't form a vector space. But even if you considered field species that did form a linear space, it would in general not naturally be a Hilbert space, and crucially it wouldn't be the Hilbert space of quantum states of the theory.

Comment: @UrsSchreiber: In http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/rie-met.pdf, it is said that "all Riemannian metrics on it can be endowed with a structure of an infinite dimensional smooth manifold modeled on the
space $D(S^2T^{*}M)$ of symmetric $\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}$-tensor fields with compact support." It can therefore be given the structure of a vector space.